# animate background position on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a div and I added a background image via CSS.  I want the image to animate to a different position on hover with jQuery.

I have everything working except for the animation is not firing.  To simplify the code, I created an example of my scenario [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y9Bv/2/).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="moveMe"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.moveMe {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: #000 0 0 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300')no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

And the problem, the jQuery:

```
 $('.moveMe')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "0% 0%"} )
    .hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "100% 0%"}, "600");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0% 0%"}, "600");
        });
```

just so you know:

- jQuery is loaded
- The jQuery code is inside of the document load function

I tried changing the animate properties to change the width on hover in out and it worked so I think my problem is with the `backgroundPosition` syntax or something.

This is driving me crazy, any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y9Bv/3/

I just switched to `background-position-x`

Comment: Thank you works like a charm!  
One thing though, can you explain to me why backgroundPosition was not working?

Thank you